# GeoServer WFS proxy error

Tags: geoserver, wfs

I'm getting a 502 proxy error when sending a wfs GetFeature request.  I think there might be multiple problems, but I'm not sure.  This URL is not working.

```
https://WEBSITE.com/geoserver/wfs?service=wfs&version=1.0.0&request=GetFeature&maxfeatures=25&srsName=EPSG:4326&outputFormat=json&CQL_FILTER=gispid = '06-03-0005-0008-0001'&typename=DC:gis2021&contentType=application/json
```

But if I change it to http and add port 8080 in the URL it works, although it's still takes way longer than it should to retrieve the data.

```
 http://WEBSITE.com:8080/geoserver/wfs?service=wfs&version=2.0.0&request=GetFeature&maxfeatures=25&srsName=EPSG:4326&outputFormat=json&CQL_FILTER=gispid%20=%20%2706-03-0005-0008-0001%27&typename=DC:gis2021&contentType=application/json
```

I have another layer that works as it should.  Still slightly slower than it should, but not as bad as the other url.  How can I get the first URL to work?

```
https://WEBSITE.com/geoserver/wfs?service=wfs&version=2.0.0&request=GetFeature&maxfeatures=25&srsName=EPSG:4326&outputFormat=json&CQL_FILTER=api%20=%20%274701300843%27&typename=DC:wells&contentType=application/json
```

EDIT: I'm have Ubuntu 20.04 and I have a reverse proxy setup under proxy.conf that looks like this.

```
ProxyRequests On

        <Proxy *>
                AddDefaultCharset off
                Order deny,allow
                Allow from all
                #Deny from all
                #Allow from .example.com
        </Proxy>
    
    ProxyVia On

    ProxyPass "/geoserver/" "http://localhost:8080/geoserver/" retry=0 timeout=5 
    ProxyPassReverse "/geoserver/" "http://localhost:8080/geoserver/"
```

Comment: we need more information, what is your proxy? how is it configured? what makes you think it's too slow?

Comment: I think it's slow because the second link takes about 30 seconds to return the data.

Comment: Do you have an index on the ID column you are filtering on?

Answer (score 2):

Okay I figured out what was wrong.  I needed to increase the timeout in proxy.conf.  It was set to 5 seconds so it was running out of time before the JSON data was returned.

```
    ProxyPass "/geoserver/" "http://localhost:8080/geoserver/" retry=0 timeout=300 
    ProxyPassReverse "/geoserver/" "http://localhost:8080/geoserver/"
```